# Creating Dataset with random Values in SAS

Tags: loops, random, sas, dataset

I want to create a random dataset. Something like this-

```
ptno visits sex race
1       1    1   0
1       2    1   0
1       3    1   0

2       1    2   1
2       2    2   1
2       3    2   1

3       1    1   0
3       2    1   0
3       3    1   0
```

The values should be randomly generated. I want to know if I can do this dynamically using do loops. Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1):

```
data want ; 
  length ptno visits sex race 8. ;
  do ptno = 1 to 100 ;
    _visits = ceil(ranuni(0)*5)  ; /* between 1 & 5 */
    sex     = ceil(ranuni(0)*2)  ; /* between 1 & 2 */
    race    = floor(ranuni(0)*2) ; /* between 0 & 1 */
    do visits = 1 to _visits ;
      output ;
    end ;
  end ;
  drop _visits ;
run ;
```

Comment: Actually this is not exactly what I wanted. For example, I have ptno from 101-110. For Each ptno there should be 5 visits and sex and race should be created accordingly. That means there should be 50 observations.

Comment: @Noob_Coder please provide that information in your original post, not in comments. This answer matches your question as posted.

Comment: @Noob_Coder, it's trivial to adjust the parameters above to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

SAS call ranuni() produce a random variate from a uniform distribution, if value is greater than 0.5 then 1, otherwise 0. Here, the same ptno (i) + seed get the same sex or race.

```
data want;
  do i=100 to 110;
     do j=1 to 5;
        seed1=i+4567;
        call ranuni(seed1,x);
        seed2=i+1234;
        call ranuni(seed2,y);
        ptno=i;
        visit=j;
        sex=(x>0.5)+1;
        race=(y<0.5);
        output;
     end;
  end;
  keep ptno--race;
run;
```